# Golang concurrently reading from a tcp connectoin

Tags: go, networking, concurrency

I am having some issue with a Go project. The code is way too big to copy and paste so I will try to explain as well as I can.

My program first connects to a TCP server, then it starts a goroutine passing as argument the connection object.

What I'm trying to achieve is having the client to read infinitely from the tcp connection while at the same time to take user input and communicate to the server by sending a retrieving data. I've tried using another goroutine but the program blocks whenever trying to retrieve data from the server.

Here is a reproduction of the error on go playground.

https://play.golang.org/p/OD5ozCRmy_4 server

https://play.golang.org/p/t1r_BAQM-jn client

Basically whenever the client tries to read from the connection it gets stuck.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are reading from the connection in both goroutines but only writing in one of them, of course this is going to block.... Unless I'm misunderstanding what the server is supposed to be sending you?

Comment: You are creating and discarding a bufio.Reader on every iteration of the loop.  This can discard data read from the network, but not yet read from the application.  Create the bufio.Reader outside of the loop.

Comment: When the code involved is too big to copy in paste, is the time to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Boiling the code down to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue is often itself a beneficial exercise in finding the cause.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thanks for your answer. My bad, the actual code creates only one reader, so unfortunately this is not the problem.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear, Thanks for your answer. So basically the server sends confirmation that a specific condition was met i.e another client connected to the server. I'm not sure how writing to the connection in both the go routines would fix this.

Comment: For starters, while reading from a `net.Conn` concurrently in 2 places is safe, it makes no sense to do so. You can't determine which parts of the stream go to which Read calls (not to mention there's hidden data buffered in the `bufio.Readers`).  I'm not sure what this is supposed to do, but there's no way to make it work

Comment: @JimB, thanks for your answer. I understand, will probably try another approach.

Comment: @Ctrl-c Edit the question to include the actual code.  It's difficult to help when the posted code is not what you are using.

Comment: @ThunderCat, I've added some sample code that recreates the same error. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Ctrl-c: your new code is different, but my previous statement still stands, reading concurrently doesn't makes sense. Also, a `bufio.Reader` is _not_ safe for concurrent access, so this new example has race conditions (always test the race detector). Just read and process the stream in a single loop.

Comment: @JimB, thanks for pointing out the race condition issue. Unfortunately it cannot read in the same loop as the client does some other actions other than communicating with the server. That part of the program would only read from the connection straight after some data has been sent to the server. That is why I was trying to find a way to have one routine read infinitely while the other does some actions and from time to time reads and writes to the server. Do you know a way in which this could be accomplished?

Comment: Read messages from one goroutine, determine target for message using message data and/or local state and dispatch to that target.

Comment: @Ctrl-c: of course you can do all the reading in one place at a time, because that how all TCP code has to be written. Use a single reader, and dispatch the actions you need done accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, really appreciated. hope I can make it work :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use channel 
here is a sample which can receive some connection and each connection could send data as wish

package tcp

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strconv"

    "../log"

    "../config"
    "../controllers"
    h "../helpers"
    )

    type msgFormat struct {
      text []byte
      net.Conn
    }

var accounts = make(map[net.Conn]int)
var conns = make(chan net.Conn)
var dconns = make(chan net.Conn)
var msgs = make(chan msgFormat)
var i int

//Init is first point
func Init() {
    startserver()
    for {
        select {
        case conn := <-conns:
            handleconnect(conn)
        case msg := <-msgs:
            go handlemsg(msg)
        case dconn := <-dconns:
            handlediscounect(dconn)
        }
    }
}
func handlemsg(incomemsg msgFormat) {
    logger.Log.Println(string(incomemsg.text))
    resp, err := controllers.Do(incomemsg.text)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    strLen := []byte(h.Lpad(string(fmt.Sprintf("%v", len(resp))), "0", 4))
    //
    fresponse := append(strLen, resp...)

    incomemsg.Write(fresponse)
    logger.Log.Println("response is %v" , string(fresponse))
}

func startserver() {
    conf := config.GetConfigInstance()

    ln, err := net.Listen(conf.SERVER.Nettype, conf.SERVER.Address)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Log.Println(err.Error())
    }
    logger.Log.Printf("server is serving at %v", conf.SERVER.Address)
    go func() {
        for {
            conn, err := ln.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                logger.Log.Println(err.Error())
            }
            conns <- conn
        }
    }()

}

func readdate(conn net.Conn, i int) {
    for {
        rd := bufio.NewReader(conn)

        dataLen := make([]byte, 4)
        _, err := rd.Read(dataLen)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        intLen, _ := strconv.Atoi(string(dataLen))
        data := make([]byte, intLen)
        _, err = rd.Read(data)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        msgs <- msgFormat{data, conn}
    }
    dconns <- conn
}

func handleconnect(newconnection net.Conn) {
    accounts[newconnection] = i
    i++
    // if addr , ok := newconnection.RemoteAddr().str
    logger.Log.Printf("Action: Client_Connected %v is connected via %v \n", i, newconnection.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr).IP)
    go readdate(newconnection, i)
}

func handlediscounect(disconnection net.Conn) {
    logger.Log.Printf("Action: Client_Disconnected %v / %v is gone\n", accounts[disconnection] + 1, disconnection.RemoteAddr().(*net.TCPAddr).IP)
    delete(accounts, disconnection)
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I've managed to get it working perfectly with channels.